# Сборка проекта на Jenkins и локально с помощью ANT

Tags: xml, jenkins, ant

Здравствуйте, в файле build.xml нужно прописать условия, при выполнении которых системе будет понятно, сборка происходит локально или на Jenkins, это делается для того, чтобы выкачивались библиотеки в определенную директорию. Для этого я определил condition

```
        <condition property="localBuildStatus"
               value="-Dproject.name=${ant.project.name} -Doutput.dist.dir=${OUTPUT_DIR}/dist -f pre_build.xml install  -Dmaven.repo.local=${maven-jenkins-repository}"
               else="-Dproject.name=${ant.project.name} -Doutput.dist.dir=${OUTPUT_DIR}/dist -f pre_build.xml install  -Dmaven.repo.local=${maven-local-repository}">
        <isset property="${WORKSPACE}"/>
        </condition>
```

Идея такова, что при сборке на JENKINS будет доступен *${WORKSPACE}*/, поэтому

```
<target name="build-tool" depends="clean-build-tool">
    <condition property="localBuildStatus"
               value="-Dproject.name=${ant.project.name} -Doutput.dist.dir=${OUTPUT_DIR}/dist -f pre_build.xml install  -Dmaven.repo.local=${maven-jenkins-repository}"
               else="-Dproject.name=${ant.project.name} -Doutput.dist.dir=${OUTPUT_DIR}/dist -f pre_build.xml install  -Dmaven.repo.local=${maven-local-repository}">
        <isset property="${WORKSPACE}"/>
    </condition>

    <exec dir="../." error="mvn_error.log" output="mvn_out.log" failonerror="true" executable="mvn.bat">
        <arg line="${localBuildStatus}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

в localBuildStatus попадёт значение *-Dproject.name=${ant.project.name} -Doutput.dist.dir=${OUTPUT_DIR}/dist -f pre_build.xml install  -Dmaven.repo.local=${maven-jenkins-repository}*, но это не выполняется. Локально все собирается, а на Jenkins нет. можете сказать, в чем проблема?

Comment: изменил условия в condition и понял, что блок condition задан неправильно, а в чем ошибка- не могу понять